# Arabic support in LiveCode

Tags: arabic, right-to-left, livecode

i use LiveCode 6.0 community edition, when i try to make a label in the GUI using an Arabic text it displays it, but from left to right not from right to left[RTL] .

is it possible to display a text in LiveCode using RTL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet unfortunately. Last time I looked into this I think you could set the text to some RTL text but you couldn't enter it RTL. Could be wrong as the project was put aside as soon as text entry was found to be LTR only.

Comment: Thanks Monte, i hope they think in adding some RTL because here we really need it :)

Comment: It is an open source project you could try to add it yourself! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Economy-x-Talk has a commercial custom software solution. It is fairly limited and I don't know if it is something for you but you could contact us at http://economy-x-talk.com.

Answer (score 1):

LiveCode 7.0 will contain support for RTL languages. This is in development and a beta is expected in March 2014.

Comment: Please note: the past has shown that RunRev's time schedules are very flexible and version number may change too. I can very well imagine that support for RTL language will appear in LC 9.0 in December 2015.

Answer (score 1):

LiveCode 7.0.0 developer preview is now available for download:
http://downloads.livecode.com/livecode/

It is the first version to natively support LTR languages and unicode.

To achieve this, several new chunk expressions have been introduced. Most importantly, the
     `trueWord` chunk expression can process text based the ICU library with its many rules taking into account many language and charset.

Please be careful, it is still a DP